# RSU location on Veins 4.7

Tags: omnet++, veins

I am trying to build a simple Veins scenario where vehicles send there information to a RSU that serves a specific junction. I am not sure how to determine the RSU location.

In the omnetpp.ini, I specified the RSU location as the Omnetpp junction location (`traci->junction("J1").getPosition()`):

```
*.rsu[0].mobility.x = 102.59
*.rsu[0].mobility.y = 58.85
*.rsu[0].mobility.z = 3
```

However this location is not reflected in the simulation kernel and the coordination of the RSU (i.e.,  `this->curPosition.info()`) is still  (0,0,0). 
Note, the SUMO Junction location is (-27.84,11.34).

If the RSU location set by the Omnet Junction location (`traci->junction("J1").getPosition()`), the rsu in the simulation GUI is far from the Vehicle that are traveling the junctions as shown in the following image:

[image: see image here]

Also, Is there a way to determine the RSU location automatically?

Comment: Have a look at https://stackoverflow.com/a/46884045/6077193

Comment: getPostion() returns the omnet coord by default in the current release.

Comment: I am guessing you are reading the curPosition attribute of your application. This is updated whenever a host moves. Because an RSU never moves, I guess it is never updated and remains uninitialized (at 0,0,0). Can you check?

Comment: Yes, for the (0,0,0) is based on the curPostion in the BaseWaveAppl class.

Comment: @Hamzah did you manage to place RSUs automatically? I need to do the same. I have been reading the source code but I can't get a starting point. If you did it successfully, It would be great if you state the steps in abstract.

Comment: @RehabShaheenEl-Qady no I did not mange to place them automatically. But, you can just write a simple script to print out  their junctions' positions in veins and then copy & paste it in the .ini file.

Comment: @Hamzah I have already did that. I wrote a script and used the equations in the traci2omnet function. There is a parameter in the equation named "margin" which I didn't know its value. But after some invistigation I found that it is configured in each scenario and its default value is set to 25.

Comment: @RehabShaheenEl-Qady I did not need to use traci2omnet.  my code was something similar to this:

`Coord tlLoc = traci->junction(anid).getPosition();
                    std::cout<<"*." + moduleName +"["<< idx << "].mobility.x = " << tlLoc.x << std::endl;`

Answer (score 0):

use the following in the .cc of the RSU:
(initialize(int stage) stage0):

```
auto RSUmobility=this->getParentModule()->getSubmodule("mobility");
double RSUx=RSUmobility->par("x").doubleValue();
double RSUy=RSUmobility->par("y").doubleValue();
double RSUz=RSUmobility->par("z").doubleValue();
```